# compare two 2d- arrays for equality in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, multidimensional-array

How can we compare two multidimensional arrays for the equality in typescript? 
My array looks like `[{"tagRuleId":3,"organisationId":454654,"tag":"third","type":1,"rule":"lirr","applicableSurveyCount":13},"tagRuleId":1,"organisationId":454654,"tag":"jj","type":1,"rule":"lllllll","applicableSurveyCount":12}]`

I have created a helper function which works only when the length changed. In case of order changed or value changed it will not work.My code so far is.

```js
isEqual(value, other) {

 // Get the value type
 var type = Object.prototype.toString.call(value);

 // If the two objects are not the same type, return false
 if (type !== Object.prototype.toString.call(other)) return false;

 // If items are not an object or array, return false
 if (['[object Array]', '[object Object]'].indexOf(type) < 0) return false;

 // Compare the length of the length of the two items
 var valueLen = type === '[object Array]' ? value.length : Object.keys(value).length;
 var otherLen = type === '[object Array]' ? other.length : Object.keys(other).length;
 if (valueLen !== otherLen) return false;

 // Compare two items
 var compare = function (item1, item2) {

  // Get the object type
  var itemType = Object.prototype.toString.call(item1);

  // If an object or array, compare recursively
  if (['[object Array]', '[object Object]'].indexOf(itemType) >= 0) {
   if (!this.isEqual(item1, item2)) return false;
  }

  // Otherwise, do a simple comparison
  else {

   // If the two items are not the same type, return false
   if (itemType !== Object.prototype.toString.call(item2)) return false;

   // Else if it's a function, convert to a string and compare
   // Otherwise, just compare
   if (itemType === '[object Function]') {
    if (item1.toString() !== item2.toString()) return false;
   } else {
    if (item1 !== item2) return false;
   }

  }
 };

 // Compare properties
 if (type === '[object Array]') {
  for (var i = 0; i < valueLen; i++) {
   if (compare(value[i], other[i]) === false) return false;
  }
 } else {
  for (var key in value) {
   if (value.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    if (compare(value[key], other[key]) === false) return false;
   }
  }
 }

 // If nothing failed, return true
 return true;

    }
```

What is wrong with this code or is there any better way to do it in angular

Comment: This has nothing to do with angular, is javascript

Comment: @CryingFreeman I am working in angular

Comment: What errors are you getting, what is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

the easiest way to compare the arrays is to convert them to JSON and compare the strings:

```
isEqual(value, other) {
  return JSON.stringify(value) == JSON.stringify(other);
}
```